# Warning: VC++ 2008 runtime libraries are not installed. Xilinx

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise

I installed the ISE from Xilinx to my windows PC and it ended up very bad. It isn't working, since when I try to run it, the next message appears `Warning: VC++ 2008 runtime libraries are not installed. Please install the runtime libraries by running the redistributable {Install Root Dir}\common\bin\nt64\vcredist_x64.exe from the installed area. You will need to have adminstrative privilege to run VC++ 2008 Redistributable.`
Obviously I went to the directory, run as administrative, repaired the C++ libraries, but nothing changed, it still failed to open.